# Trigger gitlab pipeline only on merge request on specific branch and disable for every commit

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

This example doesn't work.  I want to trigger the pipeline only on merger request and for uat branch....

````
  stage: build  
  script:
    - echo "script"
  only:
    - uat
    - merge_requests```
````

Comment: Does your script-section really have behind "merge_request" three "`"?

Answer (score 1):

You can work with rules here (see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules):

```
  stage: build  
  script:
    - echo "script"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "uat"'
```